# Is it Possbile to Check if Incoming Date is in UTC time? Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to make sure all dates that are being sent to and from my Asp.net Web Api are in UTC time.

The sending part(from the web api) is not too hard as I have control over that but I am not sure how to do it when some 3rd party would send a datetime.

I wondering if there is a way to validation it?

Comment: unless there is some reason why you cannot, highly recommend you make it understood everything in and out is UTC. your headaches will go way down and there are issues that you're going to run into beyond the scope of this question

Comment: @hubsonbropa I *used* to do UTC-only, but I found that when dealing with users (across timezones) it lost an important piece of information and encountered situations where it was very awkward to deal with (e.g. with those blasted DST changes). Granted, that while a timezone and an offset aren't strictly the same, I find protocols that deal with the offset (where such is applicable) are much easier to work with than UTC-only.

Comment: oh how I know this. done plenty both ways. end game for me is server is UTC, clients (aka users) handle localization whenever possible (which one is right when you're traveling in UK but live in NY with office in LA? server has no chance on its own figuring out which to use).

Comment: @hubsonbropa A time *with* a timezone offset can be converted to UTC. There is no problem there. The problem is when using times *without* an offset (explicit or implicit). If I say the time is now `2013-11-07T13:11:53-08:00` there is little ambiguity - yet it is *not* a UTC time.

Comment: @hubsonbropa - Is that not like saying "well "this field is required" I don't need do a check, I told them that it is required", Mistakes will happen and UTC might not be sent back. Now I am wondering if I should somehow send in timezone name in and tell them to send in local time?

Comment: all I'm getting at is APIs are meant for communicating data in the most standard way possible, and UTC is as standard as you get for date/time. requiring parties to be aware of each others localizations should be avoided when possible. that's something each party should do on its own. However as user2864740 has pointed out, sometimes it does matter and if it does in your case then you're going to need time zone data also

Comment: I get what your saying but to me it seems like it is a validation rule but guess this is one validation rule I can't enforce. I wanted all data to be standardized and then let whoever is consuming the api to deal with timezone conversions but to get to a standardized point I need some sort of validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless the timezone information is *already* included in the protocol or otherwise restricted/indicated.

This might mean there is a "Z" designation for UTC and no timezone for "local time" .. or a that a full timezone offset is specified .. or that all times are in UTC .. or it could mean something else entirely.

(This is why I have almost exclusively dropped DateTime for DateTimeOffset and *include* a timezone offset in my protocol designs whenever such must be transmitted externally.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DateTimeOffset` object to do so. Since you are the designer of the API, I highly recommend that you include this information. It is helpful to others and if you're using SQL Server for your DBMS, you can use `DATETIMEOFFSET` to ensure consistency.

If a third party is sending you a `DateTime` or equivalent, unless their protocol specifically states it is in UTC, then you cannot rely on it being in UTC and must make a guess or review the protocol documentation for some hints.

Comment: DateTime does have a Kind property that you can use to see if the time is UTC.

Comment: The problem is all in the protocol and transmission. "2008-11-20 03:04:55" says nothing about the timezone or offset by itself. (Using DATETIMEOFFSET, which I also encourage, fixes the protocol with the SQL, but not an external Web API.)